# Quisiera obtener TC compra y venta de paginas web

Tags: html, vba

quisiera obtener los TC compra y venta de las siguientes paginas y poner sus valores en celdas de un excel:

```
https://www.fintuu.com/
https://kambista.com/
https://www.rextie.com/
```

Comment: Que es TC?, que has intentado?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: @Aprendiz TC se refiere en este caso a "Tasa de Cambio".

Answer (score 1):

Con esta pequeña macros lo puedes lograr

```
Sub Obtener_TC()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://www.fintuu.com/"
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
     DoEvents
    Loop
    Range("A1").Value = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("h6")(0).innerText
    Range("A2").Value = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("h6")(1).innerText
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

que lo que hace es crear una instancia de Internet Explorer
entra a dicha pagina
espera miestrar carga la pagina
en cela A1 y A2 pone los valores de texto de los 1er. y 2do. elementos "h6" de la pagina web
luego cierra la pagina
aclaro que en ningun momento la hice visible para que no se vea feo ese parpadeo que generaria si lo hago visible y luego cerrrara